# Using int values in enum declaration

Tags: c#, enums

I want to create enum type like:

```
enum Ranks{ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, Jack, Queen, King, Ace}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: you could spell it out - `Two`, `Three`

Comment: Could you change the int's to strings "2", "3"?

Comment: @Brett: How is this supposed to work? Show us an example please.

Comment: or define a class using Card2 Card3 that can have a value property of 2?
Card2 extends Card {

Comment: It's not possible for the same reason you can't write `var 2 = "test"`. Identifiers cannot start with a number.

Comment: @DanielA.White Need to display as numbers

Comment: @TranceAddict If you mean display as in displaying to the user - that's entirely doable. But it is **impossible** to do what you are trying to do. There is no way you will be able to make the identifier simply a number.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there's no elegant way to do that, so here's a hack: Append an underscore at the beginning of each integer!

```
enum LikeThis { _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **No**

---

Regular answer: Simply **use characters** and get the numeric values like this:

```
int numericValueOne = (int)Value.Ace;
int numericValueTwo = (int)Value.Two;
```

---

Long answer: If the end usage is for a deck of cards this is a great implementation:

```
public class Card
{
    private readonly Suit _suit;
    private readonly Value _value;

    public Card(int number)
    {
        _suit = (Suit)(number / 13);  // 0 = Hearts, 1 = Diamonds ...
        _value = (Value)(number % 13 + 1);  // 1 = ace, 2 = two
    }

    public Suit Suit
    {
        get { return _suit; }
    }

    public Value Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
    }

    public int ToNumber()
    {
        return (int)_suit * 13 + ((int)_value - 1);
    }
}

public enum Suit
{
    Hearts = 0,
    Diamonds = 1,
    Clubs = 2,
    Spades = 3
}

public enum Value
{
    Ace = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
    Four = 4,
    Five = 5,
    Six = 6,
    Seven = 7,
    Eight = 8,
    Nine = 9,
    Ten = 10,
    Jack = 11,
    Queen = 12,
    King = 13,
}
```

The benefit of wrapping both enums in this class is that you can use each card as a number (0-52) and/or a class. Plus you can add whatever operations, method, properties to the class as you need and when you store or transmit the data you need only use the number. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9933234/495455)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
enum Ranks { Ace = 'A', Two = 2, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, King = 'K', Queen = 'Q', Jack = 'J' };
```

Then perform a switch on the Rank like so:

```
switch (Rank)
{
    case Ranks.Two:
    case Ranks.Three:
    case Ranks.Four:
        // Cast to an int and display it
        break;

    case Ranks.Ace:
    case Ranks.King:
    case Ranks.Queen:
    case Ranks.King:
        // Cast to char and display it
        break;
}
```

I used this in a simple blackjack game I wrote, worked well